# How do I restrict the minimum resizable width of a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: My website's minimum width vs GitHub's]

In the attached image, I'm comparing the minimum re-sizable width's of my website and GitHub's. How can I force my website to have a forced minimum width like GitHub?

I tried incorporating this code in the page's respective CSS file already:

```
body {
    min-width: 600px; 
    width: auto !important;
    width: 600px; 
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no difference and my browser can still resize smaller than the `600px` limit.

EDIT: Still no luck with the current answers.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=600, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 1):

In chrome to devtools, then click on the following icon:

[image]

Then there you can click on responsive and you can resize the browser any size you want.

this code will restrict the user from resizing:

```js
var size = [window.width,window.height];  //public variable

$(window).resize(function(){
    window.resizeTo(size[0],size[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work in this snippet because the snippet is in an Iframe. But should work in your application this includes JQuery though.

Comment: This is definitely a very useful tool, thank you. However I would like to prevent users from resizing the width of the browser they're browsing my website on past a certain point. Does that make any sense?


For example, on the GitHub website, if you were to re-size the website horizontally (shrink the width), you would not be able to after a certain point. However, on my website you can shrink it almost indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The !important width style is making the following width style redundant, so it may as well not be there at all.
Note: If the content is larger than the minimum width, the min-width property has no effect.